# Function's returned value type is either an alias ***or*** boolean

Tags: c++, function, arguments, c++17

How would we obtain a function's returned value type is either an alias ***or*** boolean once in a call (expected if possible wihout overload) ?
let's realize that function's illustration only:

```
struct U {
    int v;
}

int& f( U& u, int t ) {
      if (u.v == t) return u.v ;  // ... 
      else return (bool)0 ;      // ???
}

int main(){
  U u{7};
  int b,c, t=9;

  if (c=f(u, t)) b=c;
}
```

Thank

Comment: If you want to return a literal value (cast to `bool` is actually irrelevant), then your function needs to return by value.     An alternative would be to return an `int *`, and return a null pointer.   I suppose `std::variant` is also an answer to your question AS ASKED - since it is not possible to have a function with return type determined by the value of passed arguments -  but the example of usage you've given doesn't suggest that is appropriate.

Comment: I pretty much already said that in the answer section Peter :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
struct U {
    int v;
    inline int static  null;

};

int& f( U& u, int t ) {
      if (u.v == t) return u.v ;  // ... 
      return u.null;      // null is zero, hence (false)
}

int main(){
  U u{7};
  int b,c, t=9;

  if (c=f(u, t)) b=c;
}
```

Comment: @nonock They've created a single `int`, with `static` storage duration (so there is only one of it in your program, and it's initialised to zero), called `null` (poor choice in name really; already it's misled you! call it `zero` or something) that you can bind your reference to. You could later do `&theResultOfF == &U::null` to see if you returned that thing. It's a pattern I've used (more or less) myself more than once.... but it's hard to know from your question whether this accomplishes what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @nonock It's not `nullptr`. you can think of it as the null of this class. and the explanation for `inline static int` is given by the comment written by @ Lightness Races BY-SA 3.0

Comment: The check in `main` isn't quite right, unless `u.v` can never be zero. With this approach you need to check for _identity_ (i.e. compare addresses, not values).

Answer (score 1):

This is what [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) is for.

In this case, that'd be a `std::variant<int*, bool>`.

(You can't have a reference type as a variant option, but a pointer will suit you just fine.)

---

However, you should ensure that this is really what you want. I realise that your code is just for illustration, but if it bears *any* resemblance to your real project, I'm not convinced that the possibility of returning `(bool)0` (why didn't you write `false`?) makes sense for that function; perhaps throwing an exception would be clearer, or "out arguments", or `std::optional<int*>`.

Of course, without a concrete (non-made-up) example I can only wildly speculate as to what it is that you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Wouldn’t `std::optional<int*>` model the apparent behavior: `if (auto r = get(x)) { **r = 17; }`

Comment: @DietmarKühl I'm sorry?

Comment: You do mention `optional` but seem to primarily suggest `variant`: based on the toy example it seems the intent is to have something indicating whether the reference is successfully set. Sadly, the approach seems to require a pointer in either case: references can’t be held and it seems `std::reference_wrapper` doesn’t quite want to convert to a non-`const` reference.

Comment: I see, you're suggesting `optional<int*>`. Yes I did quickly suggest that but I don't want to go too far down the route of second-guessing what the OP wants tbh because it's really not clear atm. That part of the answer was really only a bonus on top of the actual answer to the question :P